# Error running Backendless server

Tags: deployment, backendless

I have installed [Backendless](http://www.backendless.com) standalone in my host and everything ok. But once installed, I am not able to run the `play` server. As you can see, the other services are running ok, but `play` is not.

[image]

I have tried restarting all services by `./ctlscript.sh restart` but still not working. I get:

> Play-server could not be started

In `./backendless/apps/backendless/logs/playServer.log` there is a error log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at com.backendless.redis.AbstractJedisClientManager.(AbstractJedisClientManager.java:26)
>           at com.backendless.servercode.codeBinding.EventHandlerInvoker.(EventHandlerInvoker.java:42)
>           at com.backendless.services.factory.GeoServiceBuilder.makeGeoService(GeoServiceBuilder.java:30)
>           at com.backendless.services.factory.GeoServiceBuilder.(GeoServiceBuilder.java:22)
>           at com.backendless.services.ServiceFactory.initGeoService(ServiceFactory.java:76)
>           at com.backendless.services.ServiceFactory.init(ServiceFactory.java:41)
>           at com.backendless.services.ServiceFactory.getInstance(ServiceFactory.java:54)
>           at com.backendless.util.GlobalHelper.start(GlobalHelper.java:223)
>           at com.backendless.util.GlobalHelper.onStart(GlobalHelper.java:201)
>           at Global$.onStart(Global.scala:11)
>           at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:220)
>           at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>           at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
>           at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
>           at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>           at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>           at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
>           at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
>           at play.core.StaticApplication.(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
>           at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:253)
>           at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:289)
>           at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:284)
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
>           at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:284)
>           at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala) Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>           at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
>           at com.backendless.config.RemoteConfigProvider.getConfigValue(RemoteConfigProvider.java:77)
>           at com.backendless.config.BackendlessConfig.getConfigValue(BackendlessConfig.java:37)
>           at com.backendless.config.RedisConfig.parseConfig(RedisConfig.java:135)
>           at com.backendless.config.RedisConfig.(RedisConfig.java:49)
>           at com.backendless.config.RedisConfig.(RedisConfig.java:38)
>           ... 26 more Play server process ID is 31833 14:56:56,716 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT
>   find resource [logback.groovy] 14:56:56,716 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find
>   resource [logback-test.xml] 14:56:56,716 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource
>   [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/hom
>   e/senda/backendless-3.0.0-16/apps/backendless/htdocs/play_2.11-2.3.9.jar!/logback.xml]
>   14:56:56,717 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] -
>   Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times o n the classpath.
>   14:56:56,717 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] -
>   Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/ho
>   me/senda/backendless-3.0.0-16/apps/backendless/htdocs/play_2.11-2.3.9.jar!/logback.xml]
>   14:56:56,717 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] -
>   Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/ho
>   me/senda/backendless-3.0.0-16/apps/backendless/htdocs/dao-2.1.0.jar!/logback.xml]
>   14:56:56,734 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@1ea9f6af - URL
>   [jar:file:/home/senda/back
>   endless-3.0.0-16/apps/backendless/htdocs/play_2.11-2.3.9.jar!/logback.xml]
>   is not of type file 14:56:56,851 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug
>   attribute not set 14:56:56,853 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate
>   appender of type [ch.qo s.logback.core.ConsoleAppender] 14:56:56,858
>   |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming
>   appender as [STDOUT] 14:56:56,876 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming
>   default type [ch.qos.logba ck.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder]
>   for [encoder] property 14:56:56,920 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level
>   of ROOT logger to ERROR 14:56:56,920 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching
>   appender named [STDOUT] to Logg er[ROOT] 14:56:56,920 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of
>   configuration. 14:56:56,922 |-INFO in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@6a192cfe - Registering
>   current configuration as  safe fallback point

When I reinstall Backendless I get this error:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have inside <installdir>/apps/backendless/modules/flightcontrol/flightcontrol.properties?

Comment: It should not be, seems that something went wrong during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following into *[installdir]/apps/backendless/modules/flightcontrol/flightcontrol.properties* (but change the IP and ports to the ones you set during installation, if any):

```
instances = 127.0.0.1
redis = 127.0.0.1:6379
mysql = 127.0.0.1:3306
mongodb = 127.0.0.1:27017
play = 127.0.0.1:9000
coderunner = 127.0.0.1
taskman = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Have you restarted all services?

Comment: Yes. And, a part of play and coderunner and taskmanager, all of them are working.